# convert array<uchar>^ to std::vector<char> data;

Tags: type-conversion, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I'm working with managed and unmanaged code and I need to convert
convert `array<uchar>^ image` to `std::vector<char> data`.

I've started doing this:

```
array<uchar> ^image = gcnew array<uchar>(tam);
reader2->GetBytes(0, 0, image, 0, tam);

vector<uchar> data;
for (int idxImage = 0; idxImage < tam; idxImage++)
{
    data.push_back(image[idxImage]);
}
```

It looks like it is working but it is very slow. Any idea about how can be done faster?

Comment: Will a Yes/No answer suffice for you? Or are you looking for "If yes, can you show me how?"?

Comment: I am looking for: "If yes, can you show me how?"

Comment: You should show what you have tried and where you are stuck. You are more likely to get help if you have shown an honest attempt than just asking for working code.

Comment: Those two data types are completely incompatible with each other.  So you'll have to create the std::vector and copy the elements with a foreach loop.  You already know how to do this.

Comment: Neither `vector` nor `array^` want to share their memory with another object. No matter what, you'll end up copying data from one block of memory to another. You could make memory allocation more efficient by calling `vector::reserve`, but any copy method is going to boil down to basically the same `for` loop you already have.

Comment: @DavidYaw you can do much better than a for loop (see my answer).

Comment: `memset` still has a for loop inside of it. What I was trying to say was that because the array and the vector can't share memory, it'll always have to iterate in order to copy the data; It'll always be an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first optimization you could do is to *reserve* the needed space in the vector, so it doesn't have to resize itself as you insert data into it.

This is as easy as:

```
data.reserve(tam);
```

This will improve performance, but not by that much. You can do better, you could use `memcpy`, which, as [cppreference says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

> `std::memcpy` is the fastest library routine for memory-to-memory copy.

So let's use that.

First, you need to *resize* (not *reserve*) the vector, so it knows the number of used bytes. Then, you can get a pointer to the raw data it holds with the `data()` function.

As for the array, it's a managed object, which means you need to *pin* it so the GC won't move it around. In C++/CLI this is done with `pin_ptr`.

Together, here's the final code:

```
data.resize(tam);
pin_ptr<uchar> pinned = &image[0];
std::memcpy(data.data(), pinned, tam);
```

I've tested it, and it's *much* faster. Here's a full test program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

void test1(array<uchar>^ image)
{
    std::vector<uchar> data;
    int tam = image->Length;

    auto sw = System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch::StartNew();

    for (int idxImage = 0; idxImage < tam; idxImage++)
    {
        data.push_back(image[idxImage]);
    }

    sw->Stop();
    System::Console::WriteLine("OP:      {0} ms", sw->ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

void test2(array<uchar>^ image)
{
    std::vector<uchar> data;
    int tam = image->Length;

    auto sw = System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch::StartNew();

    data.reserve(tam);
    for (int idxImage = 0; idxImage < tam; idxImage++)
    {
        data.push_back(image[idxImage]);
    }

    sw->Stop();
    System::Console::WriteLine("reserve: {0} ms", sw->ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

void test3(array<uchar>^ image)
{
    std::vector<uchar> data;
    int tam = image->Length;

    auto sw = System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch::StartNew();

    data.resize(tam);
    pin_ptr<uchar> pinned = &image[0];
    std::memcpy(data.data(), pinned, tam);

    sw->Stop();
    System::Console::WriteLine("memcpy:  {0} ms", sw->ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    size_t tam = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
    array<uchar>^ image = gcnew array<uchar>(tam);
    (gcnew System::Random)->NextBytes(image);

    test1(image);
    test2(image);
    test3(image);

    return 0;
}
```

My results are:

```
OP:      123 ms
reserve: 95 ms
memcpy:  8 ms
```